# Pip install editable poetry package fails on conflicting package version, although the exact same version is required

Tags: pip, python-poetry

```
The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested second-library 0.1.0 (from libs/second_library)
    first-library 0.1.0 depends on second-library 0.1.0 (from libs/second_library)
```

Pip version resolver fails when installing Poetry package in editable mode if package is required both by TOML file & requirements.txt file

edit:

folders structure:

```
requirements.txt
libs/first_library
libs/second_library
```

sim_requirements.txt content:

```
-e ./libs/first_library
-e ./libs/second_library
```

pyproject.toml:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
second-library = {path = "../second_library", develop = true}
```

full error log:

```
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of first-library to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Cannot install -r sim_requirements.txt (line 1) and second-library 0.1.0 (from libs/second_library) because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested second-library 0.1.0 (from libs/second_library)
    first-library 0.1.0 depends on second-library 0.1.0 (from libs/second_library)

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
```

Comment: Please add `pip --version` and full error message, as well as relevant pieces of `pyproject.toml`, `requirements.txt` (why do you have deps in both?..), `setup.py` (if you don't have it - forget `requirements.txt`, it should have no effect), and finally `tree ../libraries` (edit everything irrelevant away). Try to recreate venv and install everything anew - perhaps you tweaked something manually before and no longer remember that. If the issue persists, `pip freeze` may provide some more context too.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this exact problem and someone I work with pointed me to [this bug report](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry-plugin-export/issues/244) on the Github page. It seems to be an issue with poetry-core which is fixed in poetry-core 1.8.1 (so in poetry 1.7.1). Upgrading the version didn't fix this for me but the person in the thread [helpfully included a workaround](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry-plugin-export/issues/244#issuecomment-1787456631) which is to add the `--no-deps` argument to the `pip install` command. As far as I understand this essentially turns off the dependency solver, so while it gets around this error it might cause issues if your dependencies change.